# Ubuntu can't read hard drive after booting in windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

I have a dual boot Ubuntu / Windows 8 system. My secondary hard drive I keep all my data, and I booted into windows, changed one file, shut down, booted back into Ubuntu, and now I can't access anything on the hard drive. In File Manager it shows icons with a small padlock on each. If I emacs a file it gives me an IO error. If I try mv it gives "Read-only file system".

I've tried rebooting, remounting, with no luck. I'm a bit lost as to what to do now. I did a scan/clean with Disk Utility and it says the disk is fine.

James

Comment: Check your permissions.

Comment: ls-l says -rwxrwxr-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may happen if you hibernate the windows system. Try accessing the hard drive again from windows and see if that is possible. If yes do a complete reboot and then try to access the drive from ubuntu.

If that also does not do it, try accessing the disk with superuser access (be a bit careful here though)

Comment: I tried this, as I booted to windows it ran some sort of scan. Then I rebooted back to ubuntu, and now the drive works, but some of my files have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> My secondary hard drive I keep all my data, and I booted into windows, changed one file, shut down, booted back into Ubuntu, and now I can't access anything on the hard drive.

I assume that means you have atleast 3 partitions or drives and you don't want to access the Windows drive itself (see [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/q/145902/40581)), but 3rd partition where you have no operating system installed and only store data.

If that is an NTFS filesystem then you should run `chkdsk` [in Windows](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G#Damaged_NTFS_Filesystems).

Similar question: [Why does my NTFS partition mount as read only?](https://askubuntu.com/q/70281/40581)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'd vote this up but don't have the required reputation.