# Second drive is read only when booting with Ubuntu (Dual OS)

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, windows-10

I have **dual OS** (Ubuntu and Windows 10) on SSD and have one additional HDD.
If I boot **first** with **Ubuntu**, the **HDD is read only**.
If I boot with **Windows** first, then **reboot** with Ubuntu, Ubuntu can **write** to the HDD.
**How can I make the HDD writable, when I first boot with Ubuntu ?**

Comment: you might want to have a look at this probably: https://askubuntu.com/questions/70281/why-does-my-ntfs-partition-mount-as-read-only#70304

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have fast boot turned on in windows 10? That used to make my HDD's unreadable as well as unwriteable. Please check try this and check again :
https://in.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/37059/~/windows-10%3A-enable-or-disable-fast-startup

I turned of fast boot, while it does load my windows 10 a bit slower, I don't have to boot to windows then reboot to ubuntu to make it work.