# Why is my NTFS partition read-only?

Tags: mount, ntfs, fstab

Until now, by every boot my NTFS partition (sda3) was mounted for reading and writing and I am the owner, not root. Suddenly, I can't write to it. Here is what fstab looks like, and mount. Could it be that doual-boot Win did something? Fastboot, some flags by NTFS?

[image: screenshot1]

And here is mount cmd where it says 'ro' and permissions in Dolphion
[image: screenshot2]

[image: screenshot3]

Edit: It is not a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70281/why-does-my-ntfs-partition-mount-as-read-only), because there was a problem with ntfs-3g missing which was 2011. thing.

Comment: Check it ('fs') for errors.  If errors are detected, it will mount in read-only to protect from errors (but check your logs for the actual reason).

Comment: Some Windows updates reactivate the fastboot. So I would check whether Windows does a real complete shutdown.

Comment: Windows had yestereday some weird updates. It broke network sharing. I will check this.

Comment: FYI: `gid` is *group ID*, not User ID.  Is group #46 the group you want to have access to?  Or do you intend to have the group or user mount to be different?

Comment: You are looking at wrong partition. I am taking about sda3

Comment: I don't know your language, but according to that entry (for storage) I'd expect *root* to be the owner, not you. That should be confirmed if you traverse path to /media/storage, r. click on that folder and check permissions. Or you can open terminal, do a `ls -l /media` and check permissions on *storage* folder.