# Cannot make folders in the mounted partition

Tags: mount, filesystem, mkdir

I have mounted an NTFS partition on Ubuntu 18.04 using the `ntfsfix` command. However, I cannot create the folders either using `mkdir` or *right-click → New Folder* (the option is active, not greyed out) on that partition. It keeps giving me this error:

```
mkdir crimson
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘crimson’: No such file or directory
```

I tried `sudo` and I still get the same error. Even the `-p` option of `mkdir` keeps giving me the same error. Even `remount` didn't work. I have tried different namings and still get the same error. `mkdir` works fine in other parts of the system.

I am a newbie in the field of Linux, but I guess the problem can be addressing issue; maybe file-system commands cannot find the mounted address.

**UPDATE:** `ntfsfix` command

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda6
NTFS partition /dev/sda6 was processed successfully
```

Comment: Please add the complete `mkdir` command you've been using to your question. And also the output of `mount`.

Comment: Also please take the [tour] first, and read [ask], to learn how you can improve your questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/70281/why-does-my-ntfs-partition-mount-as-read-only

Comment: In case you are dual booting with Windows, have you disabled the Windows fast boot feature?