# Permission denied on NTFS disks

Tags: 19.10

I'm having some permissions issues with Ubuntu 19.10.
I have 3 disks:

```
sda/ 
sda1/ntfs with win10
sda2/efi
sda3/ext4 ubuntu 19.10
sdb/ntfs with files
sdc/ntfs with files
```

I've installed **qbitorrent** and cannot write to sdb but it can to sdc. I've installed **emby** also which cannot write neither sdb nor sdc.
I've been playing around with `fstab` trying different options but none of them worked.
I've also performed `sudo chown -R user:user /mount` point but same result

This is my fstab, i've tried different *dmask* and *fmask* values, also **ntfs** instead of **ntfs-3g**

```
UUID=C828D8A328D891B4 /home/user/series ntfs-3g auto,defaults,rw,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=002,fmask=113  0  0
UUID=38EC7FB0EC7F6752 /home/user/stuff ntfs-3g auto,defaults,rw,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=002,fmask=113  0  0
```

This is the result of `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 111,81 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SV300S3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb6e9d141

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048    718847    716800  350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848 192509951 191791104 91,5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       233476096 234434559    958464  468M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda4       192511998 233476095  40964098 19,5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       192903168 233476095  40572928 19,4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6  *    192512000 192903167    391168  191M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sdc: 3,65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD40EZRZ-00W
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4789F54E-36DD-4A49-B872-C95CC42433A1

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1      34     262177     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdc2  264192 7814035455 7813771264  3,7T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 1,84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: ST2000DL003-9VT1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd85e2c94

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1          63 3907027119 3907027057  1,8T 42 SFS
```

I can copy/move files with **nautilus** easily to every disk.

I'm kind of lost, I don't know what else I can try.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had a similar problem the last answer on this link helped me https://askubuntu.com/questions/70281/why-does-my-ntfs-partition-mount-as-read-only/1104709#comment1965753_1104709

Comment: As for what I had to do to mine was make sure that only the mount point was owned by my user `sudo chown $USER:$USER /mountpoint` and not all the subfolders in the NTFS.  Then on my fstab lines they only look like this:  `UUID="345A7BC14A867667" /media/WD500GB ntfs defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000 0  0`  I have full read and write capabilities to my NTFS drives.

Comment: Tried both, none worked :(

Comment: Have you booted into Windows and disabled the Fast Boot so that it doesn't put the NTFS drives into Hibernation?

Comment: I did, same problem.

Comment: well, I've solver emby's problem, I just added emby user to the group that has acceess to the drive in fstab.
`sudo usermod -a -G group emby` (group is the group added to have permissions on ntfs)
I need to find out which user does **qbitorrent** uses