# Can't paste anything or cd into hard drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

so I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my machine today and I disconnected my HDD so I can install it on the SSD cause I was afraid to erase the HDD data, first time installing Ubuntu without a VM btw, then when I connected the HDD again I found the two partitions in `/dev` as `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2` so I first tried running the `cd` command to access the HDD but it tells me that `/dev/sdb1 is not a directory`, then I tried copying a directory to the HDD to back it up and paste was grayed out, what can I do to access it.

Oh and I did some searching online most of the things I read said to mount the HDD using

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
```

but I get this message:

```
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it 
which could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

The output of the `mount | grep sdb` command was

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/ali/01D3FD2314DE1DE0 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb2 on /media/ali/01D3FD23187F1260 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Comment: Could you add to your question the output of `mount | grep sdb`.  This will show the mount options.

Comment: Try the command `mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb1`

Answer (score 1):

The `/dev/` files are hardware device nodes.  Best not to mess with those.

To see the disk, use the `df` command (display filesystems).  Output will be like:

```
 df
Filesystem       1K-blocks        Used   Available Use% Mounted on
udev               8144388          12     8144376   1% /dev
tmpfs              1631076        1008     1630068   1% /run
/dev/sda1         61414412    24208268    34456664  42% /
none                     4           0           4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                  5120           0        5120   0% /run/lock
none               8155372       80440     8074932   1% /run/shm
none                102400          60      102340   1% /run/user
```

Note that I have `/dev/sda1` mounted as my root filesystem.
The message that you are getting suggests that /dev/sdb1 is already mounted.  See if it shows up with `df`.

Comment: the two partitions showed up as `/dev/sdb1      976751968 914130100  62621868  94% /media/ali/01D3FD2314DE1DE0`

`/dev/sdb2      976760032 933519308  43240724  96% /media/ali/01D3FD23187F1260`

using the `df` command, and I can now cd into them using the path after the percentage of the partition, but when I tried copying a file to a partition I got this message:
 `cp: cannot create directory '/media/ali/01D3FD23187F1260/Acres and Karats Calculator': Read-only file system`

Comment: btw I forgot to mention I had my hard drive partitioned on windows 10 before, IDK if that will make any difference

Comment: Could you take a look at this question? https://askubuntu.com/a/70304/1030912

Comment: I tried everything in that question and still can't copy

Comment: ok so I kinda fixed it and ruined it at the same time, I unmounted both partitions in file manager then mounted /dev/sdb1 to /mnt/sdb1, then I mounted /dev/sdb1 to /mnt/sdb1 too by mistake, and now I can't find the partition sdb1 and I think I overwrote it, but it doesn't matter it only had steam games, I just wanna get that partition back