# Discrepancy in partition that I have read, write and execute permissions on

Tags: permissions, read-only

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2, and am having a problem with cutting, renaming, or moving files in my NTFS partition. It appears to be that I don't have the appropriate permissions, but when I check them I have full read, write, and execute permissions. Here's a terminal window outlining the discrepancy:

[image: Cannot move file, read-only file system]

And here is the same problem through in Nautilus:

[image: all access rights]

[image: greyed out write options]

I've run `chmod` several times; what am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my NTFS partition mount as read only?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70281/why-does-my-ntfs-partition-mount-as-read-only)

Comment: A read-only file-system means it's RO & permissions on files don't mean anything (the RO file-system is due to detected problem or other found in logs, and trumps any file-system as writing to the drive may result in data loss, so your system prevents this by flipping the *fs* to RO).   Trying to `chmod` on a RO *fs* is a waste of time & user-error, as the reason the *fs* is RO should be investigated & fixed; your system is trying to protect your data, but you want to destroy it? by writing to a problematic *fs* ?  Read your messages & explore why.

Comment: Which answer should be used? The accepted one and many others are obsolete (`ntfs-3g` is installed by default).