# Move to & delete permissions

Tags: permissions

I just migrated to Unbuntu 20.04 installed on my main SSD and I have a secondary HDD. I cannot move folders or files within that secondary disk. I tried to change permissions but although I am logged as owner and member of group permissions for others remain as read-only even when performed on the volume. Please advise.Thank you

Comment: You've provided no file-system details; but is the file-system mounted as RW (read-write)?

Comment: Hi, it seems that the drive was mounted as read-only. How can I change that? Thanks

Comment: You still haven't provided any file-system details; nor details of how you mounted it.  If it's a NTFS file-system for example and you attempted a RW mount; your logs will tell you why it flips from RW to RO which usually is a hibernated/fastboot partially-mounted file-system, but without details of what you're trying to mount we'd only be guessing (*you've not given any details on how you mounted it, let alone file-system I asked about as they give clues as to possible problems, eg NTFS I mentioned, BTRFS is a different issue etc*)

Comment: To tell the truth, the file system was that from Win 10, I just installed ubuntu on my main SSD. I don't know if the following info could help My PC have the following specs: Intel i7 (3.40 MHz), 32 GB Ram, SSD 240GB, HDD 1TB, Graphic NVidia 1070. I am sorry for the bother. thank you for keeping up with me. In fact, I installed ubuntu with encryption otherwise, I just follwed the instructions. Cheers

Comment: With windows, the common/default file-system is NTFS which I mentioned.  If you have fastboot enabled, or use hibernation, the file-system is not clean with details stored inside the hibernate file (*same for both; it speeds resuming from sleep/wake as fastboot doesn't use cold-boot*).  Your Ubuntu system will detect an *unclean* file-system, which causes it to mount only RO (read-only) to prevent dataloss.  The fix usually, is to turn off *fastboot* in windows, or not hibernate windows before using Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks a lot Guivec, I really appreciate your help. Cheers and have a nice week end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my NTFS partition mount as read only?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70281/why-does-my-ntfs-partition-mount-as-read-only)